# Check the owner type in `__set_name__` method introduced in python 3.6+ PEP-0487

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I want to check the owner class type and allow `Field` class attribute to be used with `Dataset` class or any of its subclass. That is I want other developers to not accidentally use `Field` class with any other class which is not a subclass of `Dataset`.

It seems that `Dataset` is not yet completely loaded.

The `print(f"Field: {name!r} of {owner!r} ...")`
does show that owner class is `Dataset`

But then the code fails at the next statement `if issubclass(owner, Dataset):` as python is still not aware of class `Dataset`.

```py
class Field:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        print(f"Field: {name!r} of {owner!r} ...")
        self.name = name
        if issubclass(owner, Dataset):
            raise Exception(
                f"Use the class {Field!r} only with class {Dataset!r}...."
            )

class Dataset:
    field = Field()
```

Expected to run without raising any error. But instead, I get the error that

```
Field: 'field' of <class '__main__.Dataset'>...

NameError: name 'Dataset' is not defined
```

Comment: What is that `f` before each string (getting rid of it removes the error).

Comment: @goodvibration that is a new feature called [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) introduced from python 3.6+. You might get compile error if using an older version. But this code throw error as `Dataset` is not yet loaded completely.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you'd even want to limit `Field` from being used outside of `Dataset`. Python is duck typed, and you never know what others might come up with.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because we're still in the middle of constructing the `Database` class, and it's not available in the global scope yet. I hope someone comes up with a better solution, but one workaround is to have an additional base class that does nothing:

```
class _DatasetBase:
    pass

class Field:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        print(f"Field: {name!r} of {owner!r} ...")
        self.name = name
        if not issubclass(owner, _DatasetBase):
            raise Exception(
                f"Use the class {Field!r} only with class {Dataset!r}...."
            )

class Dataset(_DatasetBase):
    field = Field()
```